# Java - Comparing bytes in files that have weird contents

Tags: java

I have a database dump program that writes out flat files of a table in a very specific format. I now need to test this against our old program and confirm the produced files are identical. Doing this manually is painful, so I need to write some unit tests.

I need to compare two file contents byte by byte, and see the first difference. The issue is they have all manner of crazy bytes with CF/LF/null's etc littered throughout.

Here is a screenshot of the two files fro Scite to give you an idea:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/screenshot1xvt.png/

What is  the best strategy for confirming each byte corresponds?

Comment: I wasn't aware that bytes really cared if they were wierd or not. Do they not read in like normal bytes if you read it in binary instead of ascii?

Comment: Do you really need to write code to do this?  There are byte-level diff programs available for free.  Otherwise, you could just load each file up into byte arrays and do a linear compare.

Comment: `LANG=C diff -q -a` *file1*  *file2* should do it.  The `-a` forces `diff` to treat the inputs as text even if they contain "weird" bytes, and the `-q` will cause it not to dump lines with unprintable bytes to output instead just reporting whether the two files are the same or different.

Comment: I would prefer code to do it, as I have thousands of table dumps to compare the output of. A linear compare could work. I was hoping to avoid doing this, as it would treat them as a long stream of bytes. Would be nice to know which line etc an error occurs on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class DominicFile {

    static boolean equalfiles(File f1, File f2) {
        byte[] b1 = getBytesFromFile(f1);
        byte[] b2 = getBytesFromFile(f2);

        if(b1.length != b2.length) return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < b1.length; i++) {
            if(b1[i] != b2[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // returns the index (0 indexed) of the first difference, or -1 if identical
    // fails for files 2G or more due to limitations of "int"... use long if needed
    static int firstDiffBetween(File f1, File f2) {
        byte[] b1 = getBytesFromFile(f1);
        byte[] b2 = getBytesFromFile(f2);

        int shortest = b1.length;
        if(b2.length < shortest) shortest = b2.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < shortest; i++) {
            if(b1[i] != b2[i]) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Returns the contents of the file in a byte array.
    // shamelessly stolen from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/file2bytearray.html
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }


}
```

Comment: @ratchet so do I honestly. It would be trivial to put this into some kind of buffered input and read it in slowly, stopping as soon as a difference is found. It's worth noting, however, that they have the same order of running time either way (with the buffering perhaps slightly slower than a single read even.)

Comment: Aside from the inefficiency, it doesn't fulfill his requirement of outputting the location of the first difference.  Since it'd be trivial to add, I think you should.

Answer (score 6):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has a `FileUtils.contentEquals(File file1, File file2)` method that seems to do what you want.  Pros:

- Looks efficient -- reads the file contents using a buffered stream, doesn't even open the files if the lengths are different.
- Convenient.

Con:

- Won't give you details about where the differences are.  It sounds from your comment like you want this.

I would say your best bet is to just download the source code, see what they're doing, and then enhance it to print out the line numbers.  The hard part will be figuring out which line you're on.  By reading at the byte level, you will have to explicitly check for `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n` and then increment your own "line number" counter.  I also don't know what kind of i18n issues (if any) you'll run into.

Comment: +1 Honestly, I would rather you use Apache Commons than my code below. Thousands (millions maybe? Don't know) of developers use it and are more likely to have weeded out any bugs than all 0 people who have used mine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do an MD5 checksum, like the one describe [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t84420.html)

Comment: Because it won't tell me where in the file the difference occurs.